# Sharing session not working on my php code

Tags: php, session, authentication, curl, session-cookies

Let'say I'm already logged in to a website. I can access it day after day simply by accessing any internal site page *without* having to submit my username and password.

At the same time I'm trying to access that site via php code running in a different tab of the same browser. I tried to use *file_get_content()* and *curl()* but the remote website server always send back the code of the login page.

So it seems that while accessing the website directly from either any browser tab or any new browser window works fine *in terms of session*, accessing the same website from php fails.

The question is: what is the difference between the way the remote website "sees" the direct access from the browser and the access made via php?

Comment: You need to send session's cookies with cURL

Comment: Thanks! that is the correct way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference depends on the header you are sending to the server. You can look like a browser and create the proper header using curl, but you probably cannot do this with the php function file_get_content.

Comment: Sorry for the GREAT late in answering. This answer gave me the clue. I succesfully gained access as desired by using cURL and session cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You did not start session transfer with:

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning of your PHP code.